# What are the corresponding commands in MathJax for \"{o} and \'{o} in Latex?

Tags: html, mathjax

In Latex \"{o} is for two dots above o and \'{o} is for uptone above o. And I am creating a website .html with MathJax for mathematical formulae and equations. But they just show as \"{o} and \'{o}. I am wondering what commands should I use to make them look correct?

Comment: Sorry, but questions about MathJax are off-topic on this site.

Answer (score 1):

I sincerly hope that you are not trying to typeset text with umlauts that way.  MathJax is *only for mathematical formulae*.  There you can use `\ddot` and `\acute`.

```
$m \ddot{o} = \acute{F}$
```

<kbd>[Live example](http://mathb.in/154591)</kbd>